# SQL: Getting all values, where a 1:N Field has same values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't get the right SQL, and I'm not sure if it is all that possible:
We have a field with an EventID, an IndividualID and a RoleID.

I need to check if an Individual has attended on Events with other Roles. So I need to count anyhow every IndividualID and check if there is more than one value of it.

Is there a possibility to do this on SQL? I think I'm missing a special expression, to make this work. If I use Count etc. it counts all Individuals but not each on it's ID.

Thanks in advance!

Example:

An Individual attended to the same Event, once as Type xx and once as Type xx2.
So this would mean:
EventID is twice the same, IndividualID is the same, but the Type and the ID of this Table is different.

Edit2: Got it, sorry guys,

```
SELECT IndividualId, EventId, COUNT(RoleId) AS cnt
FROM Tablet
WHERE EventId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY IndividualId, EventId
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I don't get it at all, I really need to learn more :)

Comment: `special expression` would be `Group by`

Comment: Could you show some sample data?

Comment: Are you saying a single individual might have attended an event, but there are multiple records with different roles for that individual? Sample data and desired output would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you just want to do:

```
SELECT IndividualId, EventId, COUNT(RoleId) as RoleCount
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
-- JOIN OTHER TABLES IF REQUIRED
GROUP BY IndividualId, EventId
ORDER BY IndividualId, EventId
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5af21/6)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Your_Table
    ([IndividualId] int, [RoleId] int, [EventId] int)
;

INSERT INTO Your_Table
    ([IndividualId], [RoleId], [EventId])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 3, 1),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 1, 2),
    (5, 1, 1),
    (5, 2, 2)
;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT IndividualId, EventId, COUNT(RoleId) as RoleCount
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
-- JOIN OTHER TABLES IF REQUIRED
GROUP BY IndividualId, EventId
ORDER BY IndividualId, EventId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5af21/6/0)**:

```
| INDIVIDUALID | EVENTID | ROLECOUNT |
|--------------|---------|-----------|
|            1 |       1 |         3 |
|            2 |       1 |         2 |
|            2 |       2 |         1 |
|            3 |       2 |         1 |
|            4 |       2 |         1 |
|            5 |       1 |         1 |
|            5 |       2 |         1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

select count(*) from tblName group by IndividualID;

Comment: Wouldn't I need to group twice at least? First on the EventID and then on the Individual?

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By this will do the work.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY IndividualID
```

Comment: SELECT Count(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY IndividualID

Comment: You can edit your answer at any time to improve it's value. I did it for now, but please do it by yourself next time. You can find the 'edit' button under your answer.

Comment: That's better, although it's won't produce the desired results as it doesn't count roles or group by events.